# MP4 video on playing in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using code: video is not playing

```
moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(new NSUrl("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
//set appearance of video player
moviePlayer.View.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 80, 300, 200);
moviePlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
moviePlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File;
// Set this property True if you want the video to be auto played on page load
moviePlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
// If you want to keep the Video player on-ready-to-play state, then enable this
// This will keep the video content loaded from the URL, untill you play it.
moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();
// Enable the embeded video controls of the Video Player, this has several types of Embedded controls for you to choose
moviePlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Default;
View.AddSubview(moviePlayer.View);
```

the `moviePlayer` will play this video at this URL: 
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8
but not this one:
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got this error:

> Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

So I added this exception in the Info.plist
:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and it will run like this:
[image]

Think when you go to release your app you should aim to use https for all links.

**Update**
Using MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
var moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerViewController(new NSUrl("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
//set appearance of video player
moviePlayer.View.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 80, 300, 200);
moviePlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File;
// Set this property True if you want the video to be auto played on page load
moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
// If you want to keep the Video player on-ready-to-play state, then enable this
// This will keep the video content loaded from the URL, untill you play it.
moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();
// Enable the embeded video controls of the Video Player, this has several types of Embedded controls for you to choose
moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Default;
View.AddSubview(moviePlayer.View);
```

If this doesnt work then I would ask another question so others can see it.

Comment: @lain can we show loader until videos are not started playing ??

Comment: I see you have just joined stackoverflow so usually we should keep it to one question per post and you should ask another question, e.g. "How to show a loading screen when using an MPMoviePlayerController?" reasons for this can be found here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/342918 Also there are other questions like that in Objective-C. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4877739/1107580 that state using MPMoviePlayerViewController rather than MPMoviePlayerController can show a loading screen. I will update my answer to show you how you would do it using that.

Comment: Also please mark @IainSmith answer as the solution so that the question is resolved :-) .

Comment: Thanks for your Response but MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated that's why I used MPMoviePlayerController